# How to test one single image in pytorch

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

I created my model in pytorch and is working really good, but when i want to test just one image **batch_size=1** always return the second class (in this case a dog).

I tried to test with batch > 1 and in all cases this works!

The architecture:

```
model = models.densenet121(pretrained=True)

for param in model.parameters():
param.requires_grad = False
from collections import OrderedDict
classifier = nn.Sequential(OrderedDict([
                          ('fc1', nn.Linear(1024, 500)),
                          ('relu', nn.ReLU()),
                          ('fc2', nn.Linear(500, 2)),
                          ('output', nn.LogSoftmax(dim=1))
                          ]))

model.classifier = classifier
```

so my tensors are [batch, 3, 224, 224]

i have tried with:

```
resize
reshape
unsqueeze(0)
```

the response when is one image is always [[0.4741, 0.5259]]

**My Test Code**

```
from PIL import *
msize = 256
loader = transforms.Compose([transforms.Scale(imsize), transforms.ToTensor()])

def image_loader(image_name):
    """load image, returns cuda tensor"""
    image = Image.open(image_name)
    image = loader(image).float()
    image = image.unsqueeze(0) 
    return image.cuda()
image = image_loader('Cat_Dog_data/test/cat/cat.16.jpg') 
with torch.no_grad():
    logits = model.forward(image)
ps = torch.exp(logits)
_, predTest = torch.max(ps,1)
print(ps) ## same value in all cases
imagen_mostrar = images[ii].to('cpu') 
helper.imshow(imagen_mostrar,title=clas_perro_gato(predTest), normalize=True)
```

**Second Test Code**

```
andrea_data = datasets.ImageFolder(data_dir + '/andrea', transform=test_transforms)
andrealoader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(andrea_data, batch_size=1, shuffle=True)
dataiter = iter(andrealoader)
images, labels = dataiter.next()
images, labels = images.to(device), labels.to(device)
ps = torch.exp(model.forward(images))
_, predTest = torch.max(ps,1) 
print(ps.float())
```

if i changed my batch_size to 1 always returned a tensor who say that is a dog [0.43,0.57] for example.

Thanks!

Comment: Please, post the code in which you run the eval with both batch>1 and batch==1.

Comment: OK, i did it now!

Comment: Can't see the eval for batch>1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I realized that my model wasn't in **eval** mode.

So i just added **model.eval()** and now that's all, works for any size batch

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code for test single image for your model train:

```
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
import torchvision.datasets as datasets
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader,Dataset
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
def pre_image(image_path,model):
   img = Image.open(image_path)
   mean = [0.485, 0.456, 0.406] 
   std = [0.229, 0.224, 0.225]
   transform_norm = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor(), 
   transforms.Resize((224,224)),transforms.Normalize(mean, std)])
   # get normalized image
   img_normalized = transform_norm(img).float()
   img_normalized = img_normalized.unsqueeze_(0)
   # input = Variable(image_tensor)
   img_normalized = img_normalized.to(device)
   # print(img_normalized.shape)
   with torch.no_grad():
      model.eval()  
      output =model(img_normalized)
     # print(output)
      index = output.data.cpu().numpy().argmax()
      classes = train_ds.classes
      class_name = classes[index]
      return class_name
```

example:

```
predict_class = pre_image("C:/Users/Salio/Desktop/example.jpeg",your_model)
print(predict_class)
```

Answer (score 0):

If your model is "correct" it just predicts a dog, you can get the label with `torch.argmax(output, dim=1)` no matter the size of `batch`.

Anyway, you shouldn't use `LogSoftmax` as activation, please use [`torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#bcewithlogitsloss) as your loss function and **remove activation from your final layer** and **output only one neuron** (probability of the image being a dog only). It would look like this in your case:

```
classifier = nn.Sequential(
    OrderedDict(
        [
            ("fc1", nn.Linear(1024, 500)),
            ("relu", nn.ReLU()),
            ("fc2", nn.Linear(500, 1)),
            # See? No activation needed
        ]
    )
)
```

You can the correct label with the above network simply by running `output > 0` + you get numerical stability "for free".

Comment: the second class is a dog but the first class is cat, the model have to choose betweeen the both, when i use Softmax the function with **NLLLoss** this return a tensor with 2 values (the probability), how i have to use correctly? because BCEWithLogitsLoss ask me a tensor [64] so i got the error ValueError: Target size (torch.Size([64])) must be the same as input size (torch.Size([64, 1]))

Comment: There is no need for first class as it will be marked as one if network's output is smaller than zero. Anything greater than that will be classified as `dog`. To fix your error you have to `flatten` your input using `input.flatten()` so it matches the target (or unsqueeze `target` via `target.unsqueeze(dim=1)`). What version of PyTorch are you using?

Comment: pytorch V. 1.1.0, ok, didn't show an error but when i train my model the acc doesn't increase, my code: https://www.codepile.net/pile/4klrGKg8